# wget does not log into ftp server without sudo

Tags: bash, ftp, wget

When I do:

```
sudo wget ${FTPpath}* -nc
```

It gets the files without a problem, but entering a password is awkward for automation.  Also just seems like bad practice.

When I leave out the sudo, it does not connect to the ftp server:

```
--2015-12-09 11:02:17--  ftp://dmanalytics:*password*@10.10.23.32/dmanalytics/download/*
           => ‘.listing’
Connecting to 197.80.203.9:3128... connected.
Logging in as dmanalytics ...
```

And then it just sits there.

I am working via a proxy, but I don't think its that.  Above it says connected, but also I tried:

```
wget ${FTPpath}* -e use_proxy=yes -e http_proxy=197.80.203.9:3128 -nc
```

without any success.  Any ideas what is causing my failure to log into the ftp server, and how I can fix my `wget` command so that I don't have to use sudo?

Comment: Check differences in the environment and .wgetrc between root and the normal user. And http_proxy is irrelevant, ftp_proxy counts.

Comment: Do you try to login with the same user `dmanalytics` in both attempts?

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.